# Using gitlab, how do I trigger CI to use a different YAML file for ansible?

Tags: ansible, continuous-integration, gitlab

I have a hypothetical .gitlab-ci.yml file:

```
stages:
- apply
run ansible playbook:
  stage: apply
  image: docker.example.com/my-ansible:2.8
  scripts:
  - ansible-playbook -i ./some-inventory -v playbook.yml
```

Here's what I'm trying to accomplish - when I upload new-inventory file and playbook file, I want the script to run ansible with those new file names. 
Is there a way to make the inventory and playbook yaml files into a variable so it picks up new files in the inventory?

So it might look like this:

```
stages:
- apply
run ansible playbook:
  stage: apply
  image: docker.example.com/my-ansible:2.8
  scripts:
  - ansible-playbook -i ./latest-uploaded-inventory -v latest-uploaded-playbook.yml
```

Comment: All of them? `for fn in $(find . -name "*.yml"); do ansible-playbook -i ./whatever-inventory "$fn" || break; done`; and if you want all inventory times all playbooks, it would be an additional `for inf in $(find . -name "*inventory"); do for fn in ...etcetc; done; done` but I doubt that's what you really want

Comment: My main goal is keeping track of the .yml configuration for different devices.  I just want to keep one project but use the same project to control different devices.  So ansible config with with ASA config wouldn't necessary match config for routers or switches.  Therefore I want to use different names for the ansible files for playbooks.  I know gitlab would just execute the pipeline as soon as I upload a different yml file in the project, so I was wondering if I can make the ansible-playbook command execute with some environment variables to use the latest uploaded playbook.

Comment: It's that "the latest uploaded playbook" part that we're trying to get to in your question. Do you mean just the changed playbook, or run all playbooks on every change, hoping for ansible's idempotency?

Comment: Just the changed playbook - thanks Matthew!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i'm understood what you wrote correctly
You are trying to run every playbook in the repo that changed in the latest commit.

So this should do it.

Make sure you installed git in the docker image.

This command returns list of all files changed in the latest commit.
`git diff --name-only HEAD^..HEAD`

```
image: alpine

before_script:
  - apk add git # If your image not contains git.

build1:
  stage: build
  script:
    - playbooks=""
    # add all changed files in latest commit to array.
    - for playbook in $(git diff --name-only HEAD^..HEAD); do playbooks="${playbooks} $playbook"; done; 
    # echo each file name, in your case change to ansible command.
    - for playbook in $playbooks; do echo $playbook; done;
```

[Here is a link to gitlab build job console output with result of the above .gitlab-ci.yml](https://gitlab.com/smuel1414/answer/-/jobs/298292829)

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks Shmuel hat is the solution I was looking for -